# Move ASP.net membership database from one server to another

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to migrate my old `ASP` project and its membership database to another server. I am currently using `SQL Server 2008`.

Is this simply done by `backup and restore`, or is there any other issues I should take care of?

**These are my specifications:**

**Old server**

- Windows server 2008 R2
- SQL server 2008
- ASP.net frame work 3.5

**New server**

- Windows server 2012 R2
- SQL server 2014 (set compatibility level to 2008)
- ASP.net frame work 4.5 (IIS8 compatible with 3.5 FW)

I am mainly concerned about moving the security database of the project.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about that database. All you need to make sure is that the correct permissions are available to the user connecting to the database on the new server.

Comment: I will check on that. Thanx